# c++ sending reference fstream to class member function issue

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to send an ifstream to a class member function called read which takes arguments int i (for size of the for loop to take in information and put it into an object of Song type) and I'm trying to get it to take an ifstream called din so that I can read these objects with my for loop above. I'm getting this error which I'm having difficulty parsing:
[My error inside the terminal environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPUq5.png)
This is how I'm trying to implement it in the main:

```
Lib1.read(times, &din);
```

In the header file:

```
void read(int i, ifstream & din);
```

and in the implementation file:

```
void Library::read(int times, ifstream & din)
```

Is there anything blatantly wrong with how I'm handling this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pointer returned from unary `&` operator won't suit for being used as  a non-const reference argument. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a pointer when a reference is needed.  Use:

```
Lib1.read(times, din);
```